# Navigation Drawer Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tengo el menu que viene por defecto en android studio, me gustaria hacer que funcione. 
Creo que seria llamando a un fragment pero no se por donde empezar.

```
MainActivity

implements  NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,BlankFragment.OnFragmentInte actionListener {

 @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        Fragment fragment;

        if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

            fragment = new BlankFragment();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
            ft.commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;

    }
```

Cuando abro el menu y elijo gallery se cierra la aplicacion

Comment: ¿Buscaste algún tutorial? Por ejemplo, [el primero que aparece](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2014/11/android-navigation-drawer-tutorial/), [en Android Developers (*inglés*)](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html), [u otros](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22como%20crear%20un%20navigation%20drawer%22) ... ¿Qué parte específica te resulta complicada?

Comment: Ecreado un fragment el problema que no me cambia de layout sino que lo supersone y si creo un segundo fragment me cierra la aplicacion

Comment: Deberías **[edit]** la pregunta agregando el código que intentaste y la descripción de lo que está fallando. Luego de agregar el código, seleccionalo y click en el botón `{  }` para darle formato.

Comment: este es el codigo que modifico espero que sirba

Comment: Si se cierra la aplicación debería salir una excepción en el depurador. Sin eso no hay mucho que hacer.